# Read single node from XML file into listBox (WP7, Silverlight, C#)

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I want to take the names of similar artists from the URL below, and display them in a listBox.

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=**ARTISTNAMEHERE**&api_key=ff1629a695c346cc4b2dd1c41fcd4054

So far from other people's questions here I've got this to read the XML file:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpCompleted;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=ARTISTNAMEHERE&api_key=ff1629a695c346cc4b2dd1c41fcd4054"));
    }

    private void HttpCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

            // do something with the XDocument here
        }
    }
```

As I said before, I want to take the artist names from that page, which is each of the name nodes and display them in a listBox. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
        XElement artists = xdoc.Root.Element("similarartists");
        if (artists != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> names = artists
                .Elements("artist")
                .Select(el => el.Element("name").Value);
        }
```

It uses methods from `System.Xml.Linq` namespace which are used to retrieve XML data by using LINQ.

Comment: I tested this in Console application, but this doesn't compile for the Windows Phone?

Comment: I looked around for other examples of IEnumerable as I've never used it before, found it works if I add a variable name after IEnumberable<string> . Only error now is it says System.Xml.Linq.Element doesn't contain a definition for Select. Any ideas? Thanks very much so far!

Comment: I added some checking to handle the situation if an artist name cannot be found.

Comment: You're welcome, you have to add `using System.Xml.Linq;` on top of your .cs file.

Comment: double checked and I definitely have that. strange.

Comment: You have to invoke `Select` on return value of `Elements` method, not `Element`. `Elements` returns `IEnumerable<XElement>` (on which you can use `Select`) and `Element` returns `XElement` which is not a collection so it doesn't have LINQ methods. Are you sure you copy-pasted this code correctly?

Comment: Turns out I missed an S. Not enough coffee obviously!